# Using stored hash values to verify authenticity of documents

Tags: hash, cryptography, sha

I am writing an application that will allow me to verify the authenticity of a document by comparing its SHA - 256 hash value with the stored hash value in my database. Outside of the unlikely event of a collision causing duplicate hashes, is there any reason this would not work? Can hash values of documents be manipulated by "end users"? Do I need a specific document signature outside of the hash using PGP? If so, why doesn't a hash value suffice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming.  [security.se] is much better suited for handling such a question.

Comment: Check out crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your help.